# Comparing Dates from API and Displaying them in a ListView in FLutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I'm having an issue where I'm not able to display the correct list based on the dates, I need the todays date, tomorrows and generally this week and next week. I'm using `Provider` for state management, I call an API and I get the dates, but when I compare them and display them in the lists respectively, they are in the wrong order or not displaying at all... So here is the code:
I call the API and fill the list in the store `DataStore`:

```
List<Data> _list = []; // here is the stored list with my Data model
List<Data> get list => _list;
Data getItemByIndex(int index) => _list[index];


  void setItems(List<Data> list) {
    _list= list;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Now I parse the `DateTime` from the list, compare if it's the same and filter the `item` list with a list of items that have the todays date, tomorrows, current week, etc.

```
bool isSameDate(DateTime other, DateTime current) { // method to check if the current date is a match to the APIs date
  return current.year == other.year &&
      current.month == other.month &&
      current.day == other.day;
}

final dataStore = Provider.of<DataStore>(context, listen: true); //calling the list from the store
final List<Data> todayItems = dataStore.list // here I defined that todayItems is a list but didn't do the same with the others
        .where((e) => isSameDate(DateTime.parse(e.pickupTime),
            DateTime.now()))
        .toList();
    final tomorrowItems = dataStore.list
        .where((e) => isSameDate(DateTime.parse(e.pickupTime),
            DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1))))
        .toList();
    final thisWeekItems = dataStore.list
        .where((e) => isSameDate(DateTime.parse(e.pickupTime),
            DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: DateTime.now().weekday - 1))))
        .toList();
```

Display the item list according to the dates:

```
Consumer<DataStore>(
                  builder: (context, storeData, child) {
                 return Column(
                         children:[
                            Column(
                               children:[
                               Text('Todays items:'), 
                                ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                 itemCount: todayItems.length,
                                   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                Data items = dataStore.getItemByIndex(index);
                               return Text('items.date');
                                      
                                }),
                            ]),
                           Column(
                               children:[
                               Text('Tomorrows items:'), 
                                ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                 itemCount: tomorrowItems.length, // this is suppose to the render 2 items if there are 2 items with the tomorrows date, right?
                                   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                Data items = dataStore.getItemByIndex(index);
                               return Text('items.date');
                                      
                                }),
                            ]),
                              Column(
                               children:[
                               Text('This week items:'), 
                                ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                 itemCount: thisWeekItems.length,
                                   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                Data items = dataStore.getItemByIndex(index);
                               return Text('items.date');
                                      
                                }),
                            ]),

                    ]);
        })
```

The problem is I get a list back but it's not the correct one, for the `todayList` I get a date that is tomorrow and sometimes it doesn't the display the whole list length, like and item is missing or so.. . I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.. Any form of help is a appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you adding 0 days to Datetime.now()

Comment: my mistake, fixed it now

Comment: are u sure the API works correctly? print the dates when u get them and see the result.

Comment: Yeah, the API works fine it returns a normal list with 2 dates when they are not filtered: ``"date":"2021-09-08T15:06:38"`` and ``"date":"2021-09-07T16:00:00"``